# How to show line with certain number of words with command sed in bash

Tags: bash, unix, sed

For example I have file like this:

```
Hel@@lo hi 123
if  a    equals  b
you
two three four
dany uri four 123
1 2 3333333
```

I need that the command will print only the lines with 3 words in it.
I tried to write command in `sed` but somehow it doesn't recognize the char `$` for the end of the line.

---

```
sed '/.\+[ ]\+.\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+$/!d' $1
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't recognize `$`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a small modification on your original code:

```
$ sed '/^[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+[ ]\+[^ ]\+$/!d' file.txt 
Hel@@lo hi 123
two three four
1 2 3333333
```

The above treats tabs as a word character, not white space.  It also assumes that there will be no leading or trailing whitespace.

Using `sed`, but allowing any type of white space and ignoring leading and trailing white space on a line:

```
$ sed -nr '/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]@]+[[:space:]]*$/p' file.txt
Hel@@lo hi 123
two three four
1 2 3333333
```

If using Mac OSX or other BSD platform, replace `-r` with `-E` as follows:

```
sed -nE '/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]@]+[[:space:]]*$/p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NF==3' file.txt


$ cat file.txt
Hel@@lo hi 123
if  a    equals  b
you
two three four
dany uri four 123
1 2 3333333

$ awk 'NF==3' file.txt
Hel@@lo hi 123
two three four
1 2 3333333
```

Comment: Is it possible to write the command only in sed? using the syntax that i wrote.